# Stream de áudio em alguns modelos de celular não funciona

Tags: android

Estou concluindo um simples stream de áudio (Web Rádio) para finalização de um projeto na minha cidade. Ainda sou novato na área de programação de `app`, porém percebi que alguns modelos de Smartphone *(Moto Xplay e Sony Xpéria)*, o stream não executa, porém fazendo os testes no meu modelo *(A5)* o stream toca normalmente.

Já declarei todas as permissões possíveis que poderia ser feita, mas não estou achando solução no caso.

```
package conciso.radioweb156natal;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b_play;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started = false;
    boolean primeiraExecucao = true;

    String url = "http://radio.imd.ufrn.br/156natal";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
        b_play.setEnabled(false);
        b_play.setText("   CONECTANDO...    ");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        new PlayerTask().execute(url);


        b_play.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                if(started){
                    started = false;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    b_play.setText("PAUSE");
                } else {
                    started = true;
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    b_play.setText("PLAY");
                }
            }

        });
    }
    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if(primeiraExecucao){
                b_play.setEnabled(true);
                b_play.setText("Pause");
                primeiraExecucao = false;
            }
            else {
                b_play.setEnabled(true);
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(prepared){
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    public void clickexit(View v) {
        started = false;
        b_play.setText("PAUSE");
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está testando com o dispositivo conectado no pc? Se sim, qual resultado do LogCat?

Comment: Opa fera,  não então, nos dispositivos que não toca o stream não estou testando conectado ao pc.

Comment: As vezes isso pode te ajudar, Formatos de Mídia para Android. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Comment: no Xperia esta gerando este erro: error (1, -2147483648) no Logcat, estou testando 2 URLS uso

Comment: fiz um pequeno script MédiaPlayer com a url pra tocar no navegador mobile no Xpéria e por incrível que pareca o stream toca perfeitamente: <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop="loop" src="http://radio.imd.ufrn.br/156natal">
<source src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
<source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
<source src="music.wav" type="audio/wav"/>
</audio>